# Как реализовать такой эффект параллакса?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

На сайте [Apple](http://www.apple.com/ru/imac-with-retina/) (блок "Самый мощный iMac в истории") есть эффект параллакса. При прокрутке до определенной точки картинка начинает прокручиваться медленнее текста, и в конце медленная прокрутка сменяется стандартной. Как можно реализовать такой же эффект?

UPD:

Есть [скрипт](https://jsfiddle.net/a1x26gdb/2/), который при прокрутке до определенной высоты замедляет прокрутку блока. Сначала у нас блок с абсолютным позиционированием, при прокрутке определенного количества пикселей блок получает фиксированное позиционирование и начинает прокручиваться медленнее основного контента.

```
        // Наш элемент, который будет замедляться
var $element = $('.first'),
    /*
    * Последняя позиция скролла, нужна
    * для вычисления
    */
    lastScrollTop = 0,
    /*
    * Отступ сверху для нашего блока 
    * с фиксированным и абсолютным
    * позиционированием
    */
    defaultElementAbsoluteTop = 150,
    defaultElementFixedTop = 90,
    // Коэффициэнт замедления
    n = 4;

    // Отслеживаем скролл страницы
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {

    // Вычисляем текущее положение
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        /*
        * Вычисляем положение нашего блока
        * от верхней части сайта/родителя.
        * Т.к. этот элемент до этого был абсолютным,
        * то у него отступ сверху всегда одинаков,
        * А когда подходит момент, когда нужно его фиксировать
        * отступ расчитывается от последнего, который был
        * 150 пикселей. Это неправильно. Я ввел проверку,
        * Если отступ стандартный абсолютный равен
        * текущему, то, при фиксировании блока
        * ставим ему оступ фиксированного блока
        * и отсюда начинаются правильные расчеты
        */
        elementTop = $element.position().top == defaultElementAbsoluteTop ? defaultElementFixedTop : $element.position().top;

    if(scrollTop < 60) 
    {
        /*
        * Проскролили меньше, чем на 60 пикселей
        * То оставляем абсолютное позиционирование
        */
        $element.removeClass('fixed');
        // И ставим элементу абсолютный отступ сверху
        $element.css({
            top: defaultElementAbsoluteTop
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // Фиксируем элемент
        $element.addClass('fixed');
        // TODO: удалить!
        //return;

        /*
        * Если прошлое положение меньше,
        * чем текущее, значит двигаемся <вниз>
        */
        if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
            // Вычисляем разницу перемещения
            var diff = scrollTop - lastScrollTop;
            // Даем отступ сверху в n раз меньше, чем скролл
            $element.css({
                top: elementTop - diff/n + 'px'
            });
        // В противном случае, двигаемся <вверх>
        } else {
            // Вычисляем разницу перемещения
            var diff = lastScrollTop - scrollTop;
            /*
            * Вычисляем результирующее положение нашего элемента,
            * с учетом замедления n
            */
            resultElementTop = elementTop + diff/n;
            /*
            * Если конечный результат вышел больше,
            * чем отступ сверху по умолчанию,
            * то даем стандартный отступ.
            * Иначе даем результирующий отступ
            */
            resultElementTop = resultElementTop > defaultElementFixedTop ? defaultElementFixedTop : resultElementTop;
            // Позиционируем элемент
            $element.css({
                top: resultElementTop + 'px'
            });
        }
    }
    // Запоминаем последнюю позицию скролла
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

Нужно, чтобы блок сначала был с position: absolute, при прокрутке до определенного участка блок получает position:fixed и прокручиваетс медленнее. При прокрутке страницы ещё ниже, блок опять становится абсолютно спизиционированным. При рокрутке обратно вверх блок получает фиксированное позиционирование и прокручивается вниз с того момента, на котором остановился при прокрутке вверх.

Comment: Там через js это разруливается: при "параллаксе" у контейнера картинки задаются `position: fixed`, а сама картинка движется через `transform: translate3d`. Когда "параллакса" нет, эти стили заменяются на другие

Comment: А как через js менять transform?

Comment: Так же как и остальные стили: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ginpei/eVtbM/light/) (не мое, нашел в гугле)

Comment: Я имел ввиду, как менять при прокрутке страницы.

Comment: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=32&id=1325 - все основано на анимации прокрутки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поковырялся, вот что получилось.

```js
firstPosScroll = []; // позиция курсора, с которой объект видим
windowH = $(window).height(); // высота окна
getPosScroll(); // заполнение вышеуказанных позиций
$(window).resize(function() { // при изменении размера окна пересчитываем позиции
  getPosScroll();
})
$(window).scroll(function() { //обработчик скролла
  posScroll = $(this).scrollTop(); // текущая позиция курсора
  posMiddle = windowH / 2; // середина окна
  $('.prlx').each(function(i, v) { // для каждого объекта
    offsetObj = $(this).offset().top; // положение объекта относительно верха документа
    posObj = offsetObj - posScroll; // текущая позиция объекта
    koef = 1 - ($(this).find('.logo').height() / $(this).find('.desc').height()); // коэффициент замедления обратно пропорционален разнице высот картинки и описания
    if (posObj < posMiddle && posObj + $(this).height() > posMiddle) { //условие видимости объекта
      $(this).find('.logo').css({
        'top': (posScroll - firstPosScroll[i] - posMiddle) * koef + 'px'
      }); // задаем высоту
    }
  });
});

function getPosScroll() {
  $('.prlx').each(function(i, v) {
    firstPosScroll[i] = $(this).offset().top - windowH < 0 ? 0 : $(this).offset().top - windowH;
  });
}
```

```css
section {position: relative;}
section.left-logo>div.logo {left: 0;}
section.left-logo>div.desc {float: right;width: 50%;}
section.right-logo>div.logo {right: 0;}
div.logo {position: absolute;width: 50%;}
section.right-logo>div.desc {float: left;width: 50%;}
header {height: 800px;background: #e6e6e6;}
img {max-width: 100%;}
div.p {margin: 20px 0;}
div.clear {clear: both;width: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<section class="left-logo prlx">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://psdcovers.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/IMAC006.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <div class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque consequatur dolore, mollitia quas quo reiciendis soluta! A beatae, temporibus? Amet animi delectus hic illo quaerat quia quos ratione rerum tempora.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Ad asperiores aspernatur assumenda blanditiis consectetur cum dignissimos dolores est facilis, fugiat hic impedit maiores minima modi molestias, natus nobis numquam optio perspiciatis possimus rem rerum tempora, tempore voluptatibus voluptatum!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Consectetur cumque exercitationem necessitatibus provident quidem, reiciendis rem similique tempore voluptatem voluptates. Accusantium consectetur deleniti dignissimos eius hic id natus perferendis, porro possimus reprehenderit similique suscipit
      tempora temporibus unde veritatis.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Accusamus aperiam, asperiores at atque beatae consectetur deleniti, dolor dolores dolorum eius excepturi exercitationem fugiat iste iure libero magni maxime molestiae nam numquam optio quibusdam reiciendis sit sunt voluptates voluptatum.
    </div>
    <div class="p">A, alias commodi incidunt iure iusto magnam minima natus, nulla odio perferendis porro veritatis. Aliquid, animi consectetur eius, exercitationem fuga impedit iusto nobis provident quibusdam quidem quisquam, soluta sunt tempore.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aliquam amet aspernatur consectetur consequuntur cum, fugiat harum hic, minima modi molestiae officia quia soluta. Assumenda eius iste nulla voluptas! Amet assumenda corporis, eaque earum illum inventore mollitia quo sit.
    </div>
    <div class="p">A consequatur corporis inventore, mollitia necessitatibus nihil nobis porro quibusdam rem voluptas! Atque blanditiis dicta dolores doloribus et facilis fugiat, harum, id laborum nam nostrum, numquam provident reiciendis unde vitae?
    </div>
    <div class="p">A accusantium amet aut, autem cum delectus deleniti, dolorem dolores ea eius, eos ex explicabo id incidunt minus molestias nam non obcaecati officiis repellat rerum similique sit suscipit veritatis voluptatibus?
    </div>
    <div class="p">Architecto cum eaque ipsa iste magnam reprehenderit sint voluptatibus. Ab asperiores atque, consequatur deserunt eum facilis id iste natus nisi obcaecati porro, praesentium quas quia rerum sit soluta unde vel?
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aperiam architecto deleniti distinctio dolor eaque eligendi est exercitationem laborum, maiores minima quasi repudiandae. Alias blanditiis, ex illum in iure magni omnis quam quibusdam quis repudiandae sint vero. Aut, voluptatibus!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Adipisci dolorum ducimus fuga harum ipsa laudantium magni maxime molestias nemo obcaecati perspiciatis quaerat qui rerum, saepe sequi voluptates voluptatum. Amet dolorem eum explicabo facilis harum inventore perferendis perspiciatis quae.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Accusamus ad, alias animi at beatae dolore doloremque excepturi explicabo fugiat ipsum iste iure iusto magnam molestiae nesciunt, praesentium quia ratione recusandae rem rerum sit tempore velit veritatis vitae voluptate!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Cumque facere quo quod! A expedita fugit inventore nostrum quis. Accusantium alias consectetur ea eveniet, harum laudantium nam officiis porro quo rerum. Expedita illo iste nihil porro reprehenderit similique sint.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Delectus dignissimos doloremque dolorum esse excepturi iste molestiae nulla quis, tempore! Aliquam aliquid architecto corporis debitis dolorem eum excepturi expedita fugiat minus modi nostrum, omnis praesentium quaerat quas, reprehenderit veniam.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Autem doloremque ea eveniet illum labore magnam, maxime molestias nobis odio omnis quam, suscipit. Ab deserunt ea esse laborum neque perferendis, porro possimus quis quos reprehenderit sequi suscipit velit vitae!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Delectus dignissimos doloribus maiores natus necessitatibus perspiciatis quia suscipit totam voluptatibus! Aliquam corporis dicta eos fugit hic magnam nihil numquam quam sunt voluptates? Amet beatae corporis, culpa quia quibusdam repudiandae?
    </div>
    <div class="p">A architecto commodi ducimus explicabo illum impedit laboriosam magni nemo perferendis quisquam! A autem deleniti deserunt fuga illum iure iusto labore necessitatibus numquam, optio perspiciatis ratione, reiciendis rerum saepe temporibus?
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aspernatur consequuntur delectus eaque eligendi eveniet harum impedit incidunt nisi nulla, odio rem repellat rerum sequi soluta temporibus vitae voluptatum? Facere minus quidem repellat temporibus unde. In saepe soluta vero.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Assumenda aut dolores eaque laborum laudantium nemo neque, placeat quod sint vero? Amet eos fuga laboriosam optio perferendis quidem repudiandae rerum saepe! Fuga ipsam nihil officia provident quos veritatis vitae!
    </div>
    <div class="p">A ab accusamus aliquid animi distinctio dolorum eius facere fugiat ipsam libero magni mollitia obcaecati odio odit, quam, rem sed soluta ullam vitae voluptas! Commodi cupiditate minima nesciunt possimus voluptatem.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Accusamus animi at atque, ea earum eligendi eos exercitationem harum illum magnam mollitia nemo neque quae quasi sint suscipit totam! Ducimus libero quidem quis repudiandae, saepe voluptatem? Ab, cum illo!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Eveniet hic neque nihil praesentium suscipit. Accusamus aperiam architecto at blanditiis consectetur consequatur doloremque dolores eligendi est, ex laboriosam mollitia nemo nobis nostrum, quaerat quia repudiandae rerum temporibus. Debitis, non.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Accusamus blanditiis cum expedita in laudantium minus natus omnis optio, provident, quam quibusdam reiciendis tempora voluptate. Aperiam assumenda optio perspiciatis placeat similique tempora vero! Corporis reiciendis veritatis voluptas! Dignissimos,
      recusandae.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Cupiditate distinctio fugiat incidunt ipsa iusto pariatur quo ratione veritatis. Adipisci amet architecto asperiores consectetur consequatur cupiditate dolorem, ducimus eveniet harum impedit, ipsa provident quo rerum saepe sint sit voluptatibus.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aliquid architecto, delectus hic numquam praesentium quibusdam quos tempora temporibus? Aliquam aliquid animi aperiam at atque beatae commodi dolores doloribus itaque iusto molestiae mollitia non quaerat quas sequi, tempore voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aperiam commodi doloremque error eum excepturi libero nobis obcaecati sint veniam voluptas. Amet aperiam autem commodi dolor eligendi, esse, expedita facere molestiae pariatur quae quisquam ratione sapiente similique tempora voluptate.
    </div>
    <div class="p">A architecto, harum laboriosam magnam necessitatibus, non optio possimus quas quasi reiciendis sit voluptate! Aperiam asperiores dolorem ducimus eveniet, fugit neque ratione temporibus? Aperiam eligendi illum incidunt maxime, quis soluta!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Ab accusamus animi aspernatur consectetur dolor dolore eligendi explicabo impedit laborum molestiae nemo, non odit, officiis, reprehenderit unde. Accusantium commodi dolorum fuga, impedit inventore optio quos sed ullam veniam voluptas.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aperiam aspernatur consectetur doloremque facere inventore, minima mollitia nesciunt quidem quisquam voluptatum. Ab accusamus aliquid at, commodi delectus deleniti dolore dolorum libero obcaecati pariatur qui ratione saepe sed temporibus unde.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Beatae commodi, consectetur culpa eaque eveniet explicabo incidunt nulla ullam. Accusantium amet animi aspernatur atque aut blanditiis cupiditate, distinctio dolore, eum illum mollitia nam nisi nostrum, possimus qui sapiente sint.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
<section class="right-logo prlx">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://psdcovers.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/IMAC006.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <div class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, dignissimos, maxime. Impedit incidunt neque provident quaerat ratione, saepe sequi voluptates. Amet assumenda commodi ducimus et maiores numquam quod sit voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Ab aliquid, cupiditate dolorem et id incidunt officiis omnis! Ad aperiam at consectetur, debitis deserunt dolor et ex explicabo minima natus odio quam quasi quo, repellendus tempore tenetur voluptas, voluptates?
    </div>
    <div class="p">A adipisci animi aperiam asperiores assumenda atque, consequatur eaque enim explicabo facilis in ipsa ipsum magni natus numquam obcaecati optio, quibusdam quod repudiandae soluta tenetur velit vero! Aliquam sunt, voluptatem.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Amet asperiores cumque, dicta eaque eos et illo impedit laborum nesciunt quis repellat tempora veritatis, voluptates voluptatibus, voluptatum. Dolorem doloribus eaque eligendi eos minus nesciunt quibusdam ratione ut voluptatem. Reiciendis.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Adipisci, at deleniti excepturi laboriosam magni necessitatibus pariatur qui recusandae rerum temporibus? Ab aperiam aut, consequatur corporis dolore eius enim esse exercitationem impedit ipsam laborum magni perferendis quam reprehenderit veniam.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aliquam dolore facilis minus quas? Accusamus adipisci at consectetur cum deleniti deserunt dignissimos et eveniet impedit incidunt iste itaque, iusto maxime nemo nihil nulla perspiciatis, possimus sunt vel velit! Illum.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aliquid aperiam ea eaque eveniet ex hic, reiciendis. Accusamus alias aliquid ea excepturi fuga laborum, maxime minima officia quisquam quos rem sed tempore, velit veritatis, voluptatem? A deserunt possimus sunt!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aperiam autem distinctio eligendi est iste. Accusamus aliquid excepturi illo officia quia reprehenderit veniam! Alias cupiditate dicta dolorum. Autem debitis delectus eum inventore iure minima nam numquam omnis quo sint!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Accusamus amet atque autem dolor enim esse est harum illum incidunt maxime necessitatibus officia quas reiciendis repellat sed tempore totam, ullam unde, vel voluptatum. Ducimus earum nesciunt possimus quos repellendus.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Corporis dicta distinctio dolorem exercitationem, inventore labore nisi placeat quasi saepe vel? Accusantium alias, debitis dolor ducimus in labore nisi nobis obcaecati officiis pariatur quasi quis, quisquam repellat temporibus vel?
    </div>
    <div class="p">Atque autem, culpa eos illum necessitatibus odio quaerat quasi quis temporibus ut veritatis voluptatum. Dignissimos eligendi laborum necessitatibus perspiciatis? Aliquam amet dignissimos doloremque eos fugiat itaque numquam possimus repellat veritatis.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Accusamus aliquam delectus deserunt dignissimos dolore eligendi est impedit laborum libero modi natus non officia pariatur quos sapiente similique ut, veniam vitae voluptas voluptates! Ad commodi excepturi numquam quasi similique!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Cumque distinctio dolorum eius fuga labore natus officia placeat quibusdam veritatis? Accusantium dolore id maiores quam qui, sapiente. Commodi eveniet fugiat maiores nam odio omnis placeat, quasi qui quidem voluptates!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Asperiores at beatae cupiditate dolore eius eveniet fugiat hic magnam, maxime minima modi mollitia nostrum numquam odit praesentium provident quaerat quia, quibusdam quis quos recusandae rem sit tempore, unde voluptatem.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Amet ex, exercitationem incidunt, ipsam libero necessitatibus nesciunt placeat quis reprehenderit temporibus, tenetur totam veritatis? At commodi cumque eaque eligendi enim fuga harum, nihil nobis praesentium qui quis sint totam.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Dignissimos est iusto molestiae molestias quaerat repellendus reprehenderit saepe tempora tempore velit! Asperiores corporis eos id, incidunt minus quisquam ratione recusandae sit tempora vero. Asperiores beatae doloremque quasi quo voluptatibus.
    </div>
    <div class="p">Accusamus aliquam assumenda consequuntur, debitis deleniti dicta eos illo, inventore itaque porro rem repellendus, voluptates. Amet dolores doloribus illo magnam molestias! Aspernatur dolorum fuga, mollitia nihil perspiciatis repellat sapiente soluta?
    </div>
    <div class="p">Aspernatur blanditiis consectetur corporis dicta incidunt itaque magni modi molestiae, mollitia nihil perferendis possimus quaerat quia quibusdam quos, repellendus similique ullam, voluptatum. Commodi facilis maxime, ratione sint sunt velit vero?
    </div>
    <div class="p">A ad aspernatur atque cumque deserunt dicta doloremque doloribus enim ex expedita explicabo, facilis fugit id iusto labore, libero magni minima necessitatibus nostrum possimus quaerat quibusdam quos recusandae sapiente temporibus!
    </div>
    <div class="p">Accusamus aliquid assumenda beatae commodi consequatur consequuntur cum, dicta eaque eius eos id illo in ipsa magni necessitatibus nisi obcaecati omnis quia recusandae sapiente similique sint vel voluptates. Aspernatur, delectus.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 8):

Мой вариант решения - [пример здесь](http://jsbin.com/kuxuvukune/edit?html,css,js,console,output). Описание всего, что происходит, в принципе, есть в коде ниже. Отчасти использовал идею со страницы Apple, но обошелся без `translate3D`.

Основной HTML:

```
<div class="content"><!-- контент --></div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="slow"></div>
  <!-- контент -->
</div>
<div class="content"><!-- контент --></div>
```

Основной CSS:

```
.content {
  position: relative;
}
.slow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $parent = $('.content').eq(1);
var $slow = $('.slow');

// сохраняем первоначальную позицию блока по отношению к родителю (100px)
var initialTop = $slow.position().top;

// эффект замедления
// то, на сколько пикселей будет двигаться блок при position: fixed
var translate = 1;

// указываем расстояние в пикселях до/после родителя, чтобы знать
// когда добавлять/убирать position: fixed
// могут быть равны 0, тогда определяться будет по позиции родителя
var parentBefore = 300,
    parentAfter = 100;


// последнее значение $window.scrollTop(), для определения направления скролла
var previousScrollTop = 0;
// направление по умолчанию - вниз
var direction = -1;

// временные переменные
var parentTop = null,
    parentBot = null;

function onScroll() {

  // узнаем в каком направлении мы сейчас скроллим
  // "1" - вверх, "-1" - вниз
  direction = previousScrollTop > $window.scrollTop() ? 1 : -1;
  previousScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

  // вычисляем верхнюю и нижнюю границу того, когда нам нужно начинать эффект
  // верхняя граница: когда топ родителя + запас "before" достигает топа окна
  // нижняя граница: когда низ родителя + запас "after" появляется снизу
  var borderTop = $parent.offset().top - parentBefore - $window.scrollTop();
  var borderBot = borderTop + parentAfter + $parent.height();

  // если мы внутри границ
  if (borderBot > $window.height() && borderTop <= 0) {

    // достаем текущее положение элемента относительно окна 
    var currentTop;
    // если скролим вверх, то при первом переключении на position: fixed,
    // восстанавливаем сохраненное значение (см. parentTop)
    if ($slow.css('position') === 'absolute') {
      currentTop = parentTop;
    } else {
      // иначе берем текущую фиксированную позицию
      currentTop = parseInt($slow.css('top'), 10);
    }

    // вычисляем новое значение со сдвигом в зависимости от направления
    var nextTop = currentTop + translate * direction;
    // проверка для того, чтобы не вылезать за пределы стартовой позиции
    if (nextTop < initialTop) {
      nextTop = initialTop;
    }

    // когда впервые попадаем в границы, добавляем запас "before" к позиции
    if (!parentTop) {
      nextTop += parentBefore;
    }

    $slow.css('position', 'fixed');
    $slow.css('top', nextTop);
    $slow.css('bottom', 'auto');

    // сохраняем позицию относительно окна сверху
    parentTop = $slow.position().top;
    // сохраняем позицию относительно окна снизу
    parentBot = $window.height() - $slow.position().top - $slow.height();

  // если вышли за границу снизу, цепляем блок к низу родителя
  } else if (borderBot < $window.height()) {
    $slow.css('position', 'absolute');
    $slow.css('top', 'auto');
    // устанавливаем позицию блока относительно родителя из сохраненного
    // значения (см. parentBot),  с вычетом запасов "before" и "after"
    $slow.css('bottom', parentBot - parentAfter + parentBefore + 'px');

  // если вышли за границу сверху, восстанавливаем все состояния
  } else if (borderTop > 0) {
    $slow.css('position', 'absolute');
    $slow.css('top', initialTop);
    $slow.css('bottom', 'auto');
    parentTop = null;
    parentBot = null;
  }

}

$window.on('scroll', onScroll);
```

Замеченные недостатки:

1. нельзя замедлять перемещение фиксированного блока меньше чем на 1px (переменная `translate`)
2. позиция блока при скролле всегда рандомная, т.к. перемещение выполняется при каждом событии `scroll`.

Правка: JSBin в Firefox не видел функцию `onScroll`, которая была объявлена под `$window.on('scroll', onScroll);`. Также Firefox даже если у элемента стоит `top:auto`, возвращает числовое значение для вызова `$el.css('top')`, а не строку `auto`.

Comment: Ваш пример по какой-то причине не работает в firefox

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Вот мой вариант:

HTML:

```
<div class="parallax"><img onload="parallax()" src="/images/image.jpg"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
.about .parallax {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.about .parallax img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
function parallax()
{
    var $block = $('.parallax');
    var $window = $(window);

    for (var i  = 0; i<$block.length; i++) {

        var $item = $($block[i]),
            docViewTop = $window.scrollTop(),
            docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height(),
            elemTop = $item.offset().top,
            elemBottom = elemTop + $item.height(),
            img = $item.find('img'),
            heightParallax = img.height() - $block.height();

        if ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)) {

            var show = docViewBottom - elemTop;
            var par = heightParallax / ($window.height() + $block.height());
            var top = par * show * -1;

            if (top > 0) {
                img.css('top', '0px');
            } else if (heightParallax < top * -1) {
                img.css('top', heightParallax + 'px');
            } else {
                img.css('top', top + 'px');
            }

        } else if (elemTop >= docViewBottom) {
            img.css('top', '0px');
        } else if (elemTop <= elemTop) {
            img.css('top', heightParallax + 'px');
        }
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    parallax();
}).resize(function() {
    parallax();
});
```

> **Результат**: [Piggy refer](https://piggyrefer.com/about)